# Can't launch using from RubyMine

Tags: ruby, rmagick, rubymine

I am having problem with RubyMine 4.0.1 on Windows 7.
Every time i run ruby script from RubyMine which contains the only line

```
require 'rmagick'
```

I recieve

```
LoadError: 126: The specified module could not be found.   - C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rmagick-2.13.1/lib/RMagick2.so
    from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:59:in `require'
    from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:59:in `rescue in require'
    from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:35:in `require'
    from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rmagick-2.13.1/lib/RMagick.rb:11:in `<top (required)>'
    from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:59:in `require'
    from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:59:in `rescue in require'
    from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:35:in `require'
    from (irb):1
    from C:/Ruby193/bin/irb:12:in `<main>'
```

But when I run the same script from cmd, everything works just fine.
I tried to change run configurations, adjusting environment variables, but nothing seemed to work.

Comment: Do you have ImageMagick dlls in system `PATH` environment?

Comment: Yes. Everything works just fine, unless i run script from RubyMine.

Comment: Try to run the script with `p ENV["PATH"]` in the command line and in RubyMine, does it produce the same output?

Comment: Oh. I am stupid. No. Output isn't the same. I tried to add environment variable "PATH" to run configuration in RubyMine (to make it identical to irb's one), but it didn't take any effect.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It turned out that the problem was caused by updated system `PATH` environment not passed to RubyMine process. New `PATH` value was passed only after machine reboot (logout should also help).

To debug such kind of issues on Windows system it's handy to use such tools like [Process Explorer](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653) (allows to verify the actual process environment) and [Rapid Environment Editor](http://www.rapidee.com/en/download) (allows to easily edit environment and detects errors in paths).

Usually it's enough to restart the process to get environment variable changes into account, but in case some custom launcher (explorer) is used, the new process may still inherit its environment and it's required to restart the parent process as well, or logout/reboot.

---

In this particular case the user has updated system `PATH` environment to include the **ImageMagick** directory that contains the DLLs required for `RMagick2.so`, however RubyMine process didn't get the new value of `PATH` after IDE restart and was still using the value without ImageMagick DLLs. After system reboot RubyMine started to use the new `PATH` value and `rmagick` gem was able to find all the dependencies.

Comment: Sorry for posting on such an old question, but since I found it, I figured others might too, and the following might be helpful. The problem for me was an outdated `PATH` as well, but restarting RubyMine fixed it, no need for logging out :) (yey, your music can keep playing ;) )